# xcode no such module error when archiving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Using cocoa pods I can build my project and run it fine, but when I try to archive I get no such module errors.  I've looked all over and tried a bunch of different things to try to solve this problem to no avail.

The one thing I've found is if I set the target build settings Build Active Architecture Only to 'Yes', I can archive just fine.  I'm not sure what that means, or why that affects it at all.. but obviously I want this value set to 'No' for the release version.

Answer (score 14):

I figured out the problem, all of the deployment targets need to be the same.  That is, in the project file, the target, and the pods project as well.

Comment: This was the problem for me too. To add one more information: I had two targets AppTarget and AppTargetArchive. Only the first was defined in the podfile as a target. From the AppTarget's "General" tab there was a framework called Pods_AppTarget.framework. An there wasn't a counterpart for the AppTargetArchive general tab. In fact I tried to add the framework manually without no luck. After the right definition of the AppTargetArchive inside the pod file the Pods_AppTargetArchive.framework appeared under the general tab of AppTargetArchive schema.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem myself. Solution for me was my custom schemes had the wrong archive build configuration. They pointed to the default release scheme which I had removed and not my new live scheme. 'Your scheme' -> edit scheme.. -> Archive -> Build configuration